# Creating a stored procedure with many-to-many relationship giving proper response

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a Stored Procedure for my school project which uses Model First.
I wanted to make a SP for returning av list of games with most orders, as a 'top list' so to speak, but can't figure it out after searching for similiar threads. The parameter @antal should return the range of distinct results to give back. So let's say I send in 5 it should return 5 Products, and 3 should return 3 products and so forth...

Since I am new to this, I'm stuck. The code so far is:

```
use SpelAffarenDatabas
go
create procedure [dbo].[GetTopListGames]
(
@antal int
)
as
select distinct top (6) p.Id, p.Name, p.Orders, k.Name, g.Name from ProduktSet as p
left join ConsoleProduct as kp
on p.Id = kp.Product_Id
left join ConsoleSet as k
on kp.Console_Id = k.Id
left join ProductGenre as pg
on p.Id = pg.Product_Id
left join GenreSet as g
on pg.Genre_Id = g.Id
group by p.Id, p.Name, p.Orders, k.Name, g.Name
```

So how do I go about getting a proper response that gives me a proper response, whic I guess would be of distinct entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select distinct top (@antal) p.Id, p.Name, p.Orders, k.Name, g.Name from ProduktSet as p
left join ConsoleProduct as kp
on p.Id = kp.Product_Id
left join ConsoleSet as k
on kp.Console_Id = k.Id
left join ProductGenre as pg
on p.Id = pg.Product_Id
left join GenreSet as g
on pg.Genre_Id = g.Id
group by p.Id, p.Name, p.Orders, k.Name, g.Name
order by p.Orders Desc
```

Comment: thats one step closer. But it is possible to get one entity, one product, into one row?